# Multiple headers are being sent when sending email via C# and IIS smtp

Tags: c#, email, smtp, iis-7.5, email-headers

I am sending emails via my C# application the way below

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(srEmail);
mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply@monstermmorpg.com", srSender);
mail.Subject = srEmailTitle;
mail.Body = srEmailBody;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Host = "127.0.0.1";
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I am using windows server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 but for mail service using IIS 6.0

Now the IIS config is the way below

[image]

I am not sure whether this problem caused by IIS or C# application so best to ask it. Thanks for the replays. The problem can be seen at the below i mean multiple received from headers

```
x-store-info:sbevkl2QZR7OXo7WID5ZcaZ0jeT0hTF6w5JqyzrMGIIJ4/L/t2gj2cA4gOeWpl7k+VkJUhAu0L19pcdx17/6zH+umIRUQcxNC7a6JMdOu4uk+atrpASsFAd6JPSp2WMA
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=temperror (sender IP is 85.17.154.139) header.from=noreply@monstermmorpg.com; dkim=none header.d=monstermmorpg.com; x-hmca=none
X-Message-Status: n:0:n
X-SID-PRA: MonsterMMORPG <noreply@monstermmorpg.com>
X-DKIM-Result: None
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: NhFq/7gR1vQcnWpWXvTdSPoVLSrfQUf9NNYiD+nue1hb767bbTKXz+tuMD66iU4vKsnCmrISnMcViv7BRc8FinIdJij0qRdzfb9MQFyl8Qnq2jH2yHHz6W3BUjjFUEclGZIdpMuV4EQ=
Received: from noreply.monstermmorpg.com ([85.17.154.139]) by BAY0-MC3-F1.Bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Sat, 10 Mar 2012 08:20:03 -0800
Received: from XCPV002 ([127.0.0.1]) by noreply.monstermmorpg.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.17514);
     Sat, 10 Mar 2012 16:20:03 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "MonsterMMORPG"
 <noreply@monstermmorpg.com>
To: mypersonalemail@hotmail.com
Date: 10 Mar 2012 16:20:03 +0000
Subject: =?utf-8?B?UG9rZW1vbkNyYWZ0IGRhaGEga2FsaXRlbGkgYmlyIG95dW4g?=
 =?utf-8?B?b2xhcmFrIGdlcmkgZMO2bmTDvC4gRXNraSBoZXNhYsSxbsSxeiBkdXJ1?=
 =?utf-8?B?eW9yLg==?=
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Return-Path: noreply@monstermmorpg.com
Message-ID: <XCPV002DreBBsQwY6YH0004e7c9@noreply.monstermmorpg.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 10 Mar 2012 16:20:03.0608 (UTC) FILETIME=[A62AC180:01CCFED9]
```

If you look carefully you will see there are 2 received from headers. I want to make it only single one. So basically removing the second received from header.

Comment: I am not sure but I think the Received here means the mail server that has processed this message as intermediates before your mail was received by the receiver.
So this is just the way it is shown in the message header at the receiver.
Why would you like to have only one of those???

Comment: Well i have fear that it would increase dropping spam box chance.

Comment: Hardly. Many companies run emails through an internal mail server before it hits the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do not use the local SMTP server. Every SMTPP server is supposed to add itself to the list for tracking. I do not really understand at all why the heck you bother - this is standard behavior.

Comment: Well i have fear that it would increase dropping spam box chance.